# Parse Credit Card input from Magnetic Stripe

Tags: asp.net, javascript, parsing, credit-card

Does anyone know how to parse a credit card string input from a Magnetic Card Swiper?

I tried a JavaScript parser but never got it to work.  This is what the input looks like.

```
%BNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN^DOE/JOHN
^1210201901000101000100061000000?;NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN=12102019010106111001?
```

The N's are the credit card number.

Comment: maybe he wants to get into the credit card terminal business?

Comment: My wife is a photographer and I'm a developer.  We just signed up with PayPal Website Payments Pro, and want to be able to process CC's on the road (trade shows and whatnot).

Comment: I did find a GreaseMonkey addin for FireFox that allows me to swipe right at the PayPal virtual terminal.  Though not ideal, it will do the trick if I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**See the [Magnetic Stripe Card entry @ Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_stripe_card#Financial_cards):**

---

> **Track one, Format B:**
>
> - Start sentinel — one character (generally '%')
> - Format code="B" — one character (alpha only)
> - Primary account number (PAN) — up to 19 characters. Usually, but not
>     always, matches the credit card number
>     printed on the front of the card.
> - Field Separator — one character (generally '^')
> - Name — two to 26 characters
> - Field Separator — one character (generally '^')
> - Expiration date — four characters in the form YYMM.
> - Service code — three characters
> - Discretionary data — may include Pin Verification Key Indicator (PVKI,
>     1 character), PIN Verification Value
>     (PVV, 4 characters), Card Verification
>     Value or Card Verification Code (CVV
>     or CVK, 3 characters)
> - End sentinel — one character (generally '?')
> - Longitudinal redundancy check (LRC) — one character (Most reader devices
>     do not return this value when the card
>     is swiped to the presentation layer,
>     and use it only to verify the input
>     internally to the reader.)

---

**<s>I hope the data is fake, otherwise</s> Anyone could get the:**

- Name
- Expiration Date
- CVV

<s>And I'm not sure but I think the credit card number (or # of possibilities) can be computed using the LRC.</s>

Comment: If you are writing to the magnetic stripe reader, and using a raw mode of writing, then computing the LRC algorithm can be a bit confusing which you must do yourself, if you use the normal mode of writing, the swipe machine will take care of that for you. But for reading, the swipe machine will automatically compute the LRC to verify the swipe was successful.

Comment: CVV is not shown in the tracks -- is it calculatable?

Comment: CVV is not in the tracks, which is intentional. It is known by the network, and used for validation that the card was present at the time the transaction occurred.

Answer (score 8):

I did you one better: I made a video showing how to do exactly this with ASP.Net/c#:

http://www.markhagan.me/Samples/CreditCardSwipeMagneticStripProcessing

Here is the section of code that you probably care about:

```
    protected void CardReader_OTC(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool CaretPresent = false;
        bool EqualPresent = false;

        CaretPresent = CardReader.Text.Contains("^");
        EqualPresent = CardReader.Text.Contains("=");

        if (CaretPresent)
        {
            string[] CardData = CardReader.Text.Split('^');
            //B1234123412341234^CardUser/John^030510100000019301000000877000000?

            PersonName.Text = FormatName(CardData[1]);
            CardNumber.Text = FormatCardNumber(CardData[0]);
            CardExpiration.Text = CardData[2].Substring(2, 2) + "/" + CardData[2].Substring(0, 2);
        }
        else if (EqualPresent)
        {
            string[] CardData = CardReader.Text.Split('=');
            //1234123412341234=0305101193010877?

            CardNumber.Text = FormatCardNumber(CardData[0]);
            CardExpiration.Text = CardData[1].Substring(2, 2) + "/" + CardData[1].Substring(0, 2);
        }
    }
```

The complete code is on that website I linked above.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can remember:

That is a two-track magnetic strip data - first track starts with `%` and ends with `?`, the second track starts with `;` and ends with `?`. These are Start/End markers.

The first track is alphanumeric, the second track is numeric, and there is a third track which is numeric also (if my memory serves correct).

The data between the start/end markers can be variable depending on the recording density of the magnetic strip. The higher the density, the more it can be recorded on one track.

Using a regex to get at the data may not be a reliable method to pick out the information required.

And not all credit cards have exactly two tracks, some uses three tracks.

Answer (score 1):

Generally for a card-not present transaction (i.e. MOTO transactions) you will need cc#, expiry and possibly the CVV (aka CVC2 etc).  You can obtain the first 2 from a card-swipe as this in the track data.  CVV is printed on the card.

Name on card doesn't matter so much.  Unless your acquirer and the cardholder are using address verification, but you can find that between ^^, it may have white space padding which you can remove.

The part you want is track2 NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN=1210 where NNNNN=card number PAN, and 1210 = Expiry date.

Even if track1 is empty (which sometimes it is as it's not used in processing), you will still get the ;?, so you could use the index of the second ; as start of the string and = as the end of the cc# string. With the 4 characters after the = as the expiry.

I would advise getting the card holder to sign something in record of the transaction otherwise they could dispute the card and do a charge-back.

> > And not all credit cards have exactly two tracks, some uses three tracks.

Only track2 is used for processing and has a standardized format.

Debit cards can't generally be processed (unless they have a visa-debit card or something).

P.S. you shouldn't store cc data in plain text, so try and keep everything in mem or strong encryption.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :
https://github.com/pdamer/CardReader/blob/master/CardReader.js
Or this:
http://blog.cnizz.com/2008/10/16/javascript-snippet-for-handling-credit-card-readers/

I think that what u need

Comment: The first link is what I was searching everywhere for. It seems to have track data validation, and even a timeout. Fortunately or unfortunately it is quite an impressive piece of code, that is simply beyond my abilities to implement. Can you add an example on how to use the CardReader function? In my track reading code, which I will add as a separate post,  I have a listener, which I don't see in CardReader.

Comment: Just posted my track reader and parser code below... need to integrate the CardReader validation

Answer (score 1):

here is my code:

1st the listener to get the data.... this data needs validation which i am looking for help on. A good swipe works fine, but a bad swipe will cause an error in the parser.

```
$('#cc-dialog-form').keypress(function(e) 
{

    var charCode = e.which;
    //ie? evt = e || window.event;
    track_start = '%';
    finished = false;
    timeout = 100;
    track_start_code = track_start.charCodeAt(0);
    //console.log('Track_start_code: ' + track_start_code);

    //console.log('keycode ' + e.keycode);


    //console.log('charcode ' + charCode);
    //console.log('track_start_code ' + track_start_code);
    if (charCode == track_start_code)
    {
        collect_track_data = true;
            $('#offline_cc_entry').hide();
            $('#cc_online').hide();
            $('#Manual_CC_DATA').hide();
            $('#cc_loading_image').show();      

    }
    if (collect_track_data)
    {   
        if (charCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) 
        {
            //all done
            //console.log( card_data);
            collect_track_data = false;
            $('#cc_loading_image').hide();
            $('#Manual_CC_DATA').show();
            //console.log("Track Data: " + card_data);


            process_swipe_cc_payment(card_data);
            card_data = '';

        }
        else
        {
            card_data = card_data + String.fromCharCode(charCode);
            console.log(card_data);
            if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
            e.returnValue=false;
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //i am guessing this will be regular input?
        if (charCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) 
        {
             process_keyed_or_offline_CC_payment();
        }
    }
    //console.log("which: " + e.which);
    //console.log("keyCode: " + e.keyCode);
    //track and collect data here?

});
```

And here is the parser.... note I put it all in one function so I can destroy all the variables so they are not lingering in a browser.

```
    parse_data = true;
if (parse_data)
{

var parsed_card_data = {};
parsed_card_data['card_data'] = card_data;
var tracks = card_data.split("?");

//console.log ("tracks");
//console.log (tracks);
parsed_card_data['track1'] = tracks[0];
parsed_card_data['track2'] = tracks[1];
//if there is a third track we might find it under tracks[2]

//splitting the card data OPTION 1

var track1_parsed = tracks[0].split("^");

//console.log (track1_parsed);



//track1 data....
var card_number_track1 = track1_parsed[0].substring(2);


parsed_card_data['card_number_track1'] = card_number_track1;

var details2_1 = tracks[1].split(";");
details2_1 = details2_1[1].split("=");


var exp_date_track_1 = details2_1[1];
exp_date_track_1 = exp_date_track_1.substring(0, exp_date_track_1.length - 1);
exp_date_track_1 = exp_date_track_1.substring(2, 4) + "/" + exp_date_track_1.substring(0,2);
parsed_card_data['exp_track1'] = exp_date_track_1;



//now check if track one matches track 2...

track2_parsed = tracks[1].split("=");


card_number_track_2 = track2_parsed[0].substring(1);



parsed_card_data['card_number_track_2'] = card_number_track_2;
exp_date_track_2 = track2_parsed[1].substring(0,4);
exp_date_track_2 = exp_date_track_2.substring(2, 4) + "/" + exp_date_track_2.substring(0,2);
parsed_card_data['exp_date_track_2'] = exp_date_track_2;


var primary_account_number =  card_number_track1.substring(0,1);


if(card_number_track1 == card_number_track_2 &&  exp_date_track_1 == exp_date_track_2)
{
        //now make a security feature showing the last 4 digits only....
    parsed_card_data['secure_card_number'] = "xxxx " + card_number_track1.substring(card_number_track1.length-4, card_number_track1.length);




    if(card_number_track1.length == 15)
    {
        parsed_card_data['card_type'] = "American Express"; 
    }
    else if(primary_account_number == 4)
    {
        parsed_card_data['card_type'] = "Visa";
    }
    else if(primary_account_number == 5)
    {
        parsed_card_data['card_type'] = "Master Card";
    }
    else if(primary_account_number == 6)
    {
        parsed_card_data['card_type'] = "Discover";
    }
    else
    {
        parsed_card_data['card_type'] = false;
    }

    var names_1 = track1_parsed[1].split("/");
    parsed_card_data['first_name'] = names_1[1].trim();
    parsed_card_data['last_name'] = names_1[0].trim();


    //console.log("return Data");
    //console.log(return_data);

}
else
{
    parsed_card_data = false;
}

    //zero out the variables...

    tracks = '';
    track1_parsed = '';
    card_number_track1 = '';
    details2_1 = '';
    exp_date_track_1 = '';
    track2_parsed = '';
    card_number_track_2 = '';
    exp_date_track_2 = '';
    primary_account_number = '';
}

if(parsed_card_data)
{
    //console.log(parsed_card_data);
    $('#card_type').val(parsed_card_data['card_type']);
    $('#credit_card_number').val(parsed_card_data['secure_card_number']);
    $('#expiration').val(parsed_card_data['exp']);
    $('#card_holder').val(parsed_card_data['first_name']+ " " + parsed_card_data['last_name']);

    //parsed_card_data['track1'] is basically what we want???

    $('#CC_SWIPE_INSTRUCTIONS').hide();
    $('#CC_DATA').hide();
    $('#cc_loading_image').show();



    var post_string = {};
    post_string['ajax_request'] = 'CREDIT_CARD_PAYMENT';
    post_string['amount'] = $('#cc_input').val();
    post_string['card_data'] = parsed_card_data;
    post_string['pos_sales_invoice_id'] = pos_sales_invoice_id;
    post_string['pos_payment_gateway_id'] = $('#pos_payment_gateway_id').val();
    post_string['line'] = 'online';
    post_string['swipe'] = 'swipe';

    card_data = '';
                parsed_card_data = {};
    var url = 'ajax_requests.php';
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: post_string,
            async: true,
            success:    function(response) 
            {
                $('#cc_loading_image').hide();
                console.log(response);
                $('#CC_RESPONSE').show();
                $('#CC_RESPONSE').html(response);
                //here we would update the payment table - currently we will just refresh

                post_string = '';

            }
            });
    post_string = '';
}
else
{
    //error
    alert("Read Error");
    $( "#cc-dialog-form" ).dialog( "close" );
}
```

Comment: I added if(card_data.indexOf('=') === -1 || card_data.indexOf('^')===-1) to validate the swipe data, which gets rid of a bad swipe, but this is not quite the same as the longitudinal redundancy checks which auth.net is requesting: "The longitudinal redundancy checks (LRC) must be calculated for the data read from the Track and compared to the LRC read from the Track. The Track data is assumed to be read without errors when no character parity errors are detected and the calculated and read LRCs match." -card present guide