# Calculate CVV from Credit card tracks?

Tags: credit-card

Can I calculate the CVV from the 3 credit card track data?
When I scan a card, there is no CVV, just the number, name and service numbers that don't relate to anything else.

Ref: [Parse Credit Card input from Magnetic Stripe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121881/parse-credit-card-input-from-magnetic-stripe)

Comment: That is somewhat the point of the CVV: that it is not in the magstripe.

Answer (score 5):

The CVV that is on the mag stripe is actually a CVC1 code, which only attempts to verify that the mag stripe details have not been tampered/corrupted. It is not the same as, nor has any relevance to the CVV code printed onto the back of the card (which is formally known as a CVC2 code.

The CVC2 that is printed onto the back of the card is (by design) intended to be viewed with eyes only, and not machine readable.

More reading : https://randomoracle.wordpress.com/2012/08/25/cvv1-cvv2-cvv3-demystifying-credit-card-data-12/

Answer (score 2):

You need two DES keys(CVK's), card no, service code, expiry to generate CVV.

```
CVV = Fun(CVK1, CVK2, card_no, service_code, expiry_YYMM);
```

There are three CVV's

```
CVV1 : in magnetic stripe
CVV2 : back of card
ICVD : in chip data
```

Service Code for each CVV differs

```
Service code for CVV1 : differs according to card type and usage 
Service code for CVV2 : 000 
Service code for ICVD : 999*
```

I have implemented following CVV generation algorithm

```
 private static final char[] decTable = "0123456789012345".toCharArray();

    private static final int hexToByte(char ch) {
        if ('0' <= ch && ch <= '9') return ch - '0';
        if ('A' <= ch && ch <= 'F') return ch - 'A' + 10;
        if ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'f') return ch - 'a' + 10;
        return -1;
    }

    /**
     * @param cvk1      : card verification key1
     * @param cvk2      : card verification key1
     * @param pan       : Account No
     * @param svc       : Service code CVV1(000), ICVV(999), CVV2(custom)
     * @param expiry    : Expiry date in YYMM format
     * @return          : CVV
     */
    public static final String calculateCVV(final String cvk1, final String cvk2, final String pan, final String svc, final String expiry) {
        String input = Strings.padRight(new StringBuilder().append(pan).append(expiry).append(svc), '0', 32);
        String data1 = input.substring(0, 16);
        String data2 = input.substring(16);
        String d1 = DES.encrypt(data1, cvk1, null, MODE.ECB, PADDING.NoPadding);
        String d2 = ByteHexUtil.byteToHex(ByteHexUtil.xor(ByteHexUtil.hexToByte(d1), ByteHexUtil.hexToByte(data2)));
        String d3 = TripleDES.encrypt(d2, cvk1 + cvk2, null, MODE.ECB, PADDING.NoPadding);
        return Decimalizer.decimalizeDigitsFirst(d3, 3);
    }
```

> //This method takes a encrypted value(hexadecimal string) as input,
>   scans for digits[0-9] and selects them to form cvv. If the no of
>   digits in input hexadecimal string is less than outLen the it starts
>   scan(excluding previously selected digits) from beginning and converts
>   hexadecimal[A-F] characters to digits using decimalization table.

```
    public static final String decimalizeDigitsFirst(String data, final int outLen) {
        StringBuilder selected = new StringBuilder(outLen);
        int selectionCounter = 0;
        int len = data.length();
        for(int i=0; i<len && selectionCounter < outLen ; i++){
            if(hexToByte(data.charAt(i)) < 10) {
                selected.append(data.charAt(i));
                selectionCounter++;
            }
        }
        if(selectionCounter !=2) {
            for(int i=0; i<len && selectionCounter < outLen ; i++){
                if(hexToByte(data.charAt(i)) > 9) {
                    selected.append(decTable[hexToByte(data.charAt(i))]);
                    selectionCounter++;
                }
            }
        }
        return selected.toString();
    }
```

Test Vectors

```
String CVK1 = "F40157F249232FCE";
String CVK2 = "7CE6C8CB9E8683EC";
String EXP_YYMM = "2005";
String SVC = "520";
String PAN = "4263970000005262";
String CVV = calculateCVV(CVK1, CVK2, PAN, SVC, EXP_YYMM);
EXPECTED CVV OUTPUT : 782
```

The output of above function is matched with output of Thales 9000 HSM with the same data. The above mentioned decimalization table is used.

Comment: what is **decTable** in **selected.append(decTable[hexToByte(data.charAt(i))]);** ?

Comment: @koding primary purpose of decimalization table is to map hexadecimal character value to some decimal character value. I have updated answer with sample decimalization table we usually use. The Card Issuer can also use decimalization table to randomize the CVV.

Comment: Thanks brother for shared it

Comment: @koding I have added context to the decimalizeDigitsFirst method. The Implementation is tested OK by comparing its output to Thales PayShield 9000 HSM output with small set of test vectors. I am planning to test it with different set of decimalization tables and large set of test vectors. I will let you know the results here once available.

Comment: @koding Added missing hexToByte method as well.

Comment: Brother, can you add example of input of cvk1, cvk2, pan, svc, expiry and result of cvv to test if that functions is worked as expected. Thanks

Comment: @koding The test vectors are updated in original answer.

Comment: @koding Earlier i said organization can choose decimalization table which is wrong. The decimalization table is fixed for cvv generation algorithm(0123456789012345).

Comment: I get that result similiar with your test vector, I change d2 to 8 bytes. Thanks brother